# How can I automatically display a legend so that it touches the border of a corner in a Matlab (R 2019b) plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

I know how to use the 'Location' input of the legend function, but none of the options put the legend right in the corner, they all leave a small space between the legend and the border of the plots. I've seen that it's possible to specify the location with a vector but I did not understand how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Static approach

Here's a way to do it. I'm using the `NorthEast` legend location as an example. For other positions you can use a similar logic (see below).

```
plot([2 -2]) % example plot...
le = legend('abc', 'Location', 'northeast'); % ... with legend

pos_le = get(le, 'position');
pos_ax = get(gca, 'position');
set(le, 'position', [pos_le(1) pos_le(2) pos_ax(1)+pos_ax(3)-pos_le(1) pos_ax(2)+pos_ax(4)-pos_le(2)]); % new position
```

To understand how this works, note that position properties are defined as

```
[lower_pos, left_pos, width, height]
```

So in this case the legend width is set to axis left position plus axis width minus legend left position; and similarly for the legend height. This logic works for a legend in the `NorthEast` location. For other locations the modification should be obvious.

## Dynamic approach

A drawback of the above is that the legend will cease to be aligned if the figure is resized. To **keep it aligned as figure size changes**, you can use the figure's `SizeChangedFcn` property to specify code that is automatically executed when the figure is resized (`ResizeFcn` also works, but it's [not recommended](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html)).

```
plot([2 -2]) % example plot...
le = legend('abc', 'Location', 'northeast'); % ... with legend

set(gcf, 'SizeChangedFcn', 'le = findobj(gcf, ''type'', ''legend''); pos_le = get(le, ''position''); pos_ax = get(gca, ''position''); set(le, ''position'', [pos_le(1) pos_le(2) pos_ax(1)+pos_ax(3)-pos_le(1) pos_ax(2)+pos_ax(4)-pos_le(2)]);')

set(gcf, 'position', get(gcf, 'position')-1e-3) % force initial call to SizeChangedFcn
set(gcf, 'position', get(gcf, 'position')+1e-3) % restore initial position
```

Example:

[image]